# JSONP request issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

Recently I have replaced `xmlHTTPRequest` with a JSONP request for my web service calls, but I found that I'm getting errors due to it. I could see that JSONP is a little slower.

```
initialize:function(){
  this.callParent();
  var jsonObject = Ext.create('MyProj.library.webservice').makeJSONPRequest('top_categories_json');
  Ext.getCmp('categoryList').setData(jsonObject.info);
  console.log(jsonObject.info);
}
makeJSONPRequest: function(urlx, postparams) {
  Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    params:{
      params:  Ext.JSON.encode(postparams)
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('JSON RES');
      console.log(result.info);
      if (result) {
        //return JSON.parse(result);
        return result;
      } else {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error retrieving the weather.');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I could see that after executing the `makeJSONPRequest` call, it executes the next stateemnt without waiting for the JSONP request to finish, so `jsonObject` becomes undefined. After that error the JSONP request finishes and prints the value. Anyway to suspend the main thread until the JSONP request finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Calls to your service are async. You really need to put all logic in the callback handler. Or generates an event after you receive a response and handle that event.